# Empty web form for validation after adding custom filter to Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, authentication

I have a Spring 4 web application with a standard authentication - username and password. For the validation I use a form-baked bean, javax.validation and Hibernate validator:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class SignupForm {

    @Size(min = 6, message = "must be at least 6 characters")
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    // get / set methods
}
```

Then in Spring Security I had a standard configuration that worked for me.

Here is how I use it in the controller and it worked:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createRecruiter(@ModelAttribute("signUpForm") @Valid SignupForm signupForm,
        BindingResult formBinding, HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (formBinding.hasErrors()) {
        UiUtil.addError(request, EntryError.SINGUP_VALIDATION_ERROR);
        return DEFAULT_REDIRECT;
    }
    // rest of the method is not important
 }
```

Now I want to open my API for public use using HMAC authentication. For this purpose I followed [a step by step guide](http://massimilianosciacco.com/implementing-hmac-authentication-rest-api-spring-security). In it simplified  so there isn't example on how to cope with multiple authentication providers and such.

You can see that you need to add custom filter for REST authentication to the Spring configuration in it's filter chain.

In Spring context configuration class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    // standard configuration
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new RestSecurityFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

I also have added the authentication provider to the authentication manager like this:

```
@Autowired
private RestAuthenticationProvider restAuthProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    auth.authenticationProvider(restAuthProvider);
}
```

The problem is that now in the controller the `SignupForm` object has only `null` values set to its fields but the request parameters are set right. If I remove the `RestSecurityFilter` from the configuration it works!

How to make the validation work with the `RestSecurityFilter` in the chain?

What I've tried already and it didn't work (obviously):

- Removed the custom authentication provider - `auth.authenticationProvider(restAuthProvider);`. I thought that it could be a multiple `AuthenticationProviders` problem.
- Add the `RestSecurityFilter` both - before and after the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.
- Made `RestSecurityFilter`'s doFilter method only execute `chain.doFilter(request, response)`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments that might help:

- I would use a spring-mvc interceptor, rather than a `Filter`. It's a bit more high-level and spring-mvc natvie
- you should not use the "form" terminology for a RESTful service, and you should not redirect on error (you should instead return the proper error response)
- you don't need `ModelAttribute` in the signature